# Nested ListView only displays first selected data

Tags: asp.net, listview

I'm trying to make work a nested ListView for days now, but I can't figure out why it only shows the first selected data. Here is some code:
aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListForumCategories" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="accordionButton">
                <table><%--class="Categories"--%>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="CatName">
                            <%# Eval("CatName") %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="SubjectNumber">
                            0
                        </td>
                        <td class="AllComment">
                            0
                        </td>
                        <td class="CreationDate">
                            <%# Eval("WhenCreated") %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="LastModification">
                            <%# Eval("WhenCreated") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListSubjectsToCategories" DataSource='<%# Eval("RelatedSubjects") %>' runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="accordionContent"><%# Eval("SubjID") %> <%# Eval("SubjectName") %> <%# Eval("WhenCreated") %></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

queries

```
public static List<ForumCategoriesModel> ListForumCategories()
        {
            try
            {
                return BW_Model.ForumCategories.Select(x => new ForumCategoriesModel
                {
                    CatID = x.CatID,
                    CatName = x.CatName,
                    WhenCreated = x.WhenCreated
                }).ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exceptions.SomethingWrongException();
            }
        }
public static List<ForumSubjectsModel> ListForumSubjectByCategoryID(int catid)
        {
            try
            {
                return BW_Model.ForumSubjects.Select(x => new ForumSubjectsModel
                {
                    SubjID = x.SubjID,
                    WhoCreated = x.WhoCreated,
                    WhichCategory = x.WhichCategory,
                    SubjectName = x.SubjectName,
                    SubjectText = x.SubjectText,
                    WhenCreated = x.WhenCreated
                }).Where(x => x.WhichCategory == catid).ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exceptions.SomethingWrongException();
            }
        }
```

class

```
public class ForumCategoriesModel
    {
        public Int32 CatID { get; set; }
        public String CatName { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }
        public List<ForumSubjectsModel> RelatedSubjects { get { return bw_forum_sqlchannel.ListForumSubjectByCategoryID(CatID); } }
    }
public class ForumSubjectsModel
    {
        public Int32 SubjID { get; set; }
        public Int32 WhoCreated { get; set; }
        public Int32 WhichCategory { get; set; }
        public String SubjectName { get; set; }
        public String SubjectText { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

I should get a List<> back, with lots of elements, but it only displays the first one for each category.

Trying to solve this for 2 days now... if you could help me out, that would be really appriciated. Thanks in advance.

ah and forgot the behind code :):

```
categories = bw_forum_sqlchannel.ListForumCategories();
ListForumCategories.DataSource = categories;
ListForumCategories.DataBind();
```

the solution:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListSubjectsToCategories" DataSource='<%# Eval("RelatedSubjects") %>' runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="accordionContent"><%# Eval("SubjID") %> <%# Eval("SubjectName") %> <%# Eval("WhenCreated") %></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

became:

```
<div class="accordionContent">
<asp:ListView ID="ListSubjectsToCategories" DataSource='<%# Eval("RelatedSubjects") %>' runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("SubjID") %> <%# Eval("SubjectName") %> <%# Eval("WhenCreated") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the `RelatedSubjects` property contain the expected data, and the problem is that all of it is not shown in the inner `ListView`? Or is it so that the `RelatedSubjects` does not even fetch all the rows that it should?

Comment: @user1429080 well i don't know, i couldn't test it.
the output of the listview is like this:
[code]first category
   first item belongs to first category
second category
   first item belongs to second category[/code]
but there should be more items belonging to these categories, but it only displays the 1st. i think probably relatedsubjects has all the data, however im not sure about it

Comment: @user1429080 wow, i found it in the page source... how the hell can the CSS cause this? :D let me try to fix it.

Comment: @user1429080 yeah, the dropdown jquery's div messed it up... thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason could be:

1. The `ListForumSubjectByCategoryID` only returns one record
2. Something weird is going on with the inner `ListView`
3. Everything is ok except the browser for some reason is not showing all the data

Based on the code you have provided (which seems sane, and a quick test of my own shows that it should work), the problem is likely the third option.

Can you check by viewing the source of the rendered page to see it the content is there? If so, you need to investigate your CSS to figure out why the browser is only showing the first line.